# Rundeck: Saved Log Filter not visible to all Users?

Tags: rundeck

I created a log-filter to filter logs for specific jobs in a project to see those failed jobs. I created this log-filter as admin user. But when I login as other users , that log filter is not visible to choose from for those users, possibly privilege issue ? Instead I can search manual but then as logged in as a user other than admin if I want to save that search log-filter its not saving and no error shown as well.
My requirement is I want to save some log-filters for few jobs and make it available to all limited privilege users to use it.
Is there any aclpolicy I can add to do it. Please share how I can achieve it.

Rundeck Version : 3.3.1

OS : CentOS 8

Backend: MySQL

Java: 8

Answer (score 0):

Researching the internal Rundeck architecture, that values (filters) are linked to users. If you check [your filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzWdN.jpg) and later check the [database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZQt6.jpg) it seems that filters are linked to users. You can suggest that as enhancement [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues) or add the same filter to other users.